# H2o without webserver

Tags: python, webserver, rhel, h2o

I just installed h2o (python) on my linux VM. The server admin doesnt allow use of webserver on VM, hence I can't use a localhost. Is there a way i can still use H2o on my VM.  Can I create a fake local server or something to tricks h2o into believing that these is a web server.

Whenever i try to do a h2o.init() i get the following error.

[image]

Comment: Can you install a VM on your VM? That is the only thing I can think of. 

Blocking all ports on localhost is fairly extreme. Just blocking ports under 1024 is surely sufficient even for the most paranoid system admin?  (See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/96418/31291 for the only attack vector I could find.)

Answer (score 0):

When using H2O with Python, it uses a client-server architecture where Python is the client and H2O is the server.

The REST API for H2O is exposed via the web port you mention, so you cannot just disable it.

However if you look at the following documentation, there are options for securing it, including authentication and HTTPS:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/security.html